# Match to XML files and transfer tag values?

Tags: php, xml, match, simplexml

I have two XML files and I want to transfer specified values from one XML file to the other XML file where the names are matching. If there is no value where the games are matching, I want to add the tag anyway but it should be empty.

Does anybody knows how I can do that?

Here is an example:

data.xml

```
<products>
    <product>
        <title>iPhone 7</title>
        <desc>Here is a desc</desc>
    </product>
    <product>
        <title>iPhone 6</title>
    </product>
</products>
```

And I want to transfer the value of `desc` in this XML file where the names are matching. If there is no value in in `desc` in the `data.xml` file, I want to add `""` to the `here.xml` file. Like this:

here.xml

```
<products>
    <product>
        <title>iPhone 7</title>
        <desc>Here is a desc</desc>
    </product>
    <product>
        <title>iPhone 6</title>
        <desc></desc>
    </product>
</products>
```

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: Hi, as it stands, this question feels like it's asking us to do all the work, rather than help you with one particular part of the problem. Try breaking the problem down into smaller parts, such as: opening the two XML files and looping through their contents; matching elements from one array to elements from another; writing values into a particular place in an existing XML file; then combining these parts to solve your original aim. If you get stuck on a particular part, you'll have a much better question for this site, because you can show us what you've tried.

Comment: Exactly here I have my question. Is there a smarter way then looping through each XML file? - For example, loading both XML files into an array? - And I know how to match XML values. But my problem is to transfer the `desc` value into the other XML file..